# The MS Graph /sites?search= returns no results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I use the MS Graph API and call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=`, I get this response

> {
>       "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
>       "value": [] }
>
> request-id →cfb68a16-eb50-42ab-950c-fbfeec4def5c

But I am able to get the root site details using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root` with response

> {
>       "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
>       "createdDateTime": "2014-12-03T12:55:35.73Z",
>       "description": "",
>       "id": "fake.sharepoint.com,2d114e0b-41de-4069-b821-6f48b3f58dcb,25f9f0b9-d0bc-4c8b-aee8-03d9ed04532d",
>       "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-04-17T09:59:59Z",
>       "name": "",
>       "webUrl": "https://fake.sharepoint.com",
>       "displayName": "Fake Team Site",
>       "root": {},
>       "siteCollection": {
>           "hostname": "fake.sharepoint.com"
>       } }
>
> request-id →6635a7a2-babb-4473-9057-d467c4f1eaaa

Shouldn't the `/sites?search=` return *ALL* the sites within the tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding an `*` to the end of the URI? That should return all sites including sub-sites.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

Graph Explorer can be a useful tool where you can test what permissions are needed for your request.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Comment: Dear pal.illesy, it would be nice if you post some code. explaining you recommendation.

Comment: Agree with @Artem here, could you please post some code example for this. I did try using `*` which still gives me the same response. The work around I used to get this working is using the MS Sharepoint search call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview
I even wrote up a small validation script to compare the Graph and Sharepoint search results, found some interesting results where Sharepoint search returned the desired results almost all the time (we still see odd behaviours though)

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge its based on what type of authentication you are using.

- if its a delegated permission type then you get a response with value parameter empty.
- if you are using the app only permission then you can get the all sites in the tenant.

have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts).